# Bluetooth programming on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, communication

I am trying to create a app on android that uses bluetooth to communicate with my PC. I want to send text from android app and receive text/events from PC app. Can anyone guide me on how to make the two communicate? or guide me to some resource?

Answer (score 6):

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) walks through almost everything you'll need.  And there is also a [Bluetooth chat sample application](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) that comes with the SDK.

Comment: yeah I checked that out. Cant remember why I drifted away from it. I am trying to connect my android app with my java app on comp and it only accepts UUID as 1101. I mean I tried adding a UUID using [this](http://www.uuidgenerator.com/) but it gives me an error with the generated UUID. What do I do?

Comment: I mean the server app on comp accepts only 1101 not the generated UUID.

Comment: Is the device paired to the computer? You can use any UUID you want as long as the client and server agree what they are.  I assume that createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() is what is failing on the device.  Can you post your code?  That may help.

Comment: Hi, Did you write the Server App yourself? Bluetooth Servers have "hard coded" UUID's identifying them. If you did not write the server party yourself, you *cannot* change the UUID. If you wrote the server yourself, you probably have hard coded in 1101 somewhere around the ServerSocket creation.

Answer (score 3):

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html) walks through almost everything you'll need. And there is also a Bluetooth chat sample application that comes with the SDK.

Also check following URL:

http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/Android-Bluetooth.htm

Answer (score 1):

After learning from my previous answer you can download the file from following link
in this i created a Bluetooth Server for PC and an Android client to transfer files but first carefully go through the previous answer and then download the file and then read the Read Me first.txt file for installation instruction

https://rapidshare.com/files/3100729241/Read%20Me%20First.rar

Comment: the above link may not work because the policy of the rapidshare site the site will delete the file if it were not downloaded more than 90days as i know thanks