# Is there any possibility to sync data between two android mobiles

Tags: android, mobile

I developed an application called 'Security alarm system' which have a hardware(gateway).It should be operated from two or more mobiles.So,data in application database should be same for all mobiles.I am using Sqlite database and I have done application in eclipse.Is it possible to sync the application database table's data between two mobiles.If possible,help me with the sample code...Please help me as I am new to android.

Comment: can anyone answer my question please.....

Comment: ya sure.Please answer my question,it is very important for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607173/unsecured-bluetooth-connection-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736468/bluetooth-programming-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432788/android-app-bluetooth

Comment: Is there any other procedure other than bluetooth for syncing of data programatically.